# Does Anchoring fall under any of Robert Cialdini's influence buckets?

Tags: social-psychology

Robert Cialdini discusses 7 major influence buckets in his 2 books (Influence, Pre-suasion)

Being:

1. Social Proof.
2. Personal Consistency & Commitment.
3. Authority.
4. Unity.
5. Reciprocity.
6. Scarcity.
7. Liking.

The concept of Anchoring brought up nicely in this video https://youtu.be/uqXVAo7dVRU?t=136 does not seem to fall under any of the above stated buckets.

Does anchoring fall under any of the above buckets or is it its own separate bucket?